# Fastest way to check if the the most recent result for a patient has a certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Mssql < 2005

I have a complex database with lots of tables, but for now only the patient table and the measurements table matter.

What I need is the number of patient where the most recent value of `'code'` matches a certain value. Also, datemeasurement has to be after '2012-04-01'. I have fixed this in two different ways:

```
SELECT
COUNT(P.patid)
FROM T_Patients P
WHERE P.patid IN (SELECT patid
                        FROM T_Measurements M WHERE (M.code ='xxxx'  AND result= 'xx')  
                AND datemeasurement = 
                    (SELECT MAX(datemeasurement) FROM T_Measurements 
                     WHERE datemeasurement > '2012-01-04' AND patid = M.patid
                     GROUP BY patid
                        GROUP by patid)
```

AND:

```
SELECT
            COUNT(P.patid)
            FROM T_Patient P


WHERE 1 = (SELECT TOP 1 case when result = 'xx' then 1 else 0 end 
        FROM T_Measurements M 
    WHERE (M.code ='xxxx')  AND datemeasurement > '2012-01-04' AND patid = P.patid
    ORDER by datemeasurement DESC
)
```

This works just fine, but it makes the query incredibly slow because it has to join the outer table on the subquery (if you know what I mean). The query takes 10 seconds without the most recent check, and 3 minutes with the most recent check.

I'm pretty sure this can be done a lot more efficient, so please enlighten me if you will :).

I tried implementing `HAVING datemeasurment=MAX(datemeasurement)` but that keeps throwing errors at me.

Comment: Shouldn't this be :
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM T_Measurements  WHERE code ='xxxx'  AND result= 'xx'  
AND datemeasurement = > '2012-01-04'

Comment: What version of MSSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my approach would be to write a query just getting all the last patient results since 01-04-2012, and then filtering that for your codes and results. So something like

```
select 
    count(1) 
from
    T_Measurements M 
    inner join (
            SELECT PATID, MAX(datemeasurement) as lastMeasuredDate from
            T_Measurements M
            where datemeasurement > '01-04-2012'
            group by patID
            ) lastMeasurements 
    on lastMeasurements.lastmeasuredDate = M.datemeasurement
       and lastMeasurements.PatID = M.PatID
where
    M.Code = 'Xxxx' and M.result = 'XX'
```

Comment: Do you have reason to assume that this will be faster than my alternatives?

Comment: It will definitely perform better than the second query, which requires some sort of lookup in the execution plan for each patient's last measurement, versus just building that table one time and joining to it.

Comment: As for the first query, it depends on your indexes and the density of your columns a bit, but again you'll have at best an index scan against your patids to get their last measurement. This is the minimal amount of IO given that you can't do windowing functions. It sounds counterintuitive, but getting every patient's last measurement results once and finding those with the codes will generally be faster than getting each patient with the codes and looking up their individual last measurement date.

Comment: How would rewrite this in the form `FROM T_Patients`, as I need that as the main table because the query is generated dynamically, and I'm not always looking up measurements. Furthermore, I have a whole list of criteria the patients must match, so I need that table to be in there.

Comment: Fixed it with an inner join on the T_Measurement Join on T_patients. Much faster!!

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way may be to use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(m.patid)
from (select m.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by patid order by datemeasurement desc) as seqnum
      FROM T_Measurements m
      where datemeasurement > '2012-01-04'
     ) m
where seqnum = 1 and code = 'XXX' and result = 'xx'
```

`Row_number()` enumerates the records for each patient, so the most recent gets a value of 1.  The result is just a selection.

Comment: This looks good but I need to check if it's usable in my setup. This query is only part of the full query, where I was using subqueries as building blocks to gather a whole list of quality indicators. So selecting from the subquery will most likely not work. Do you think you can rewrite this in a way that it can be used in the sample queries (so select from t_patients Where....).

Comment: @saratis . . . I really don't understand your comment.  If you want the list of patids, just change the `select` to `select m.patid`.  That can then be used in other queries to join to other patient information.

Comment: I understand that you don't understand :). I will try that tomorrow and see if it's faster than 3 minutes :).

Comment: Server: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 25
'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name.
Unfortunately I'm forced to work with a very old  version of MSSQL :(